# Angular Como Puedo Compartir Componentes de un proyecto hacia otro proyecto en el mismo servidor?

Tags: angular, framework, microservices

Tengo  una Duda con respecto a Angular Framework , quiero fraccionar mi app-web en componentes que se encuentren en proyectos diferentes.

La finalidad es dividir las vistas con su logica de backend  en diferentes proyecto tipo Micro Servicios. Existe Alguna manera de implementar angular como micro-servicios ?
[image: Adjunto Explicación grafica]

EJEMPLO:Exite un proyecto principal que gestiona componentes o modulos privados que vienen de otros proyectos desplegados en el mismo servidor.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Ricardo, escribí una respuesta, pero en realidad hay otra alternativa: [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) que te permite utilizar los componentes incluso fuera de contextos de Angular. Tal vez un poco mas de detalles en cuanto como y donde piensas utilizar los componentes, podría ayudar a dar una mejor respuesta

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Los componentes que quieres compartir deben pertenecer a módulos. Estos módulos deben exportar el componente en cuestión

---

Si sigues la guía para tener una estructura de [múltiples proyectos](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects)

```
my-workspace/      (mono-repo, carpeta principal de los proyectos)
  ...             (configuración global del espacio de trabajo)
  projects/       (aplicaciones y librerías generadas)
    my-first-app/ --(una aplicación)
      ...         --(configuraciones específicas de la aplicación)
      src/        --(archivos fuente de la aplicación)
    my-second-app/ --(otra aplicación)
      ...         --(configuraciones específicas de la aplicación)
      src/        --(archivos fuente de la aplicación)
    promos/       --(proyecto de promociones)
      ...         --(configuraciones especificas)
      src/        --archivos fuente de promos)
        promos.component.ts     --(componente de promociones)
        promos.module.ts        --(modulo de promos)
```

Suponiendo que vas a crear un componente de promociones, estaría en la carpeta de `promos`

1. Crear un componente

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-promos',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let promo of promos">
       {{promo.title}}
    </div>
  `
})
export class PromosComponent {
  @Input()
  promos: Promocion[]
}
```

2. El modulo de promos debe declarar y exportar el componente

```
@NgModule({
  declaration: [
    PromosComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    PromosComponent,
  ],
})
export class HelloWorld {}
```

Ahora desde cualquier modulo de otro proyecto puedes importar el modulo y utilizar el componente.